# Merge rows when value is column A is the same

Tags: vba, excel

I have rows of data in excel.

I want to merge the rows with the same value in column A. I've seen some solutions that use formula but I'd prefer to do VBA considering the volume of data.

The overall plan is to analyse the most common values in each coalesced column

**From**:

```
A   x   x   x   x
B   x   x
B   x   x   x   x   x   x
B   x   x   x
C   x   x
C   x   x   x
C   x   x   x
D   x   x
D   x   x
D   x   x
```

**To**:

```
A   x   x   x   x
B   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x
C   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x
D   x   x   x   x   x   x
```

---

I started writing something in VBA (it's flawed), but I'm wondering if there's a better approach.

```
Sub Merge_Row()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    i = 2
    Sheets("MergeDatabase").Select
    Do Until Cells(i, 1) = ""
        If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
            Cells(i, 2).Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
            Selection.Cut
            Cells(i - 1, 1).Select
            Selection.End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, unless it just didn't get pasted in, you appear to be missing two instances of "End With" to close out your "With" statements.

```
With application
   .ScreenUpdating = False
   .EnableEvents = False
   .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Version 1 bellow uses arrays and dictionaries so it's very fast, but doesn't copy cell formatting

Version 2 is quite a bit slower using just copy / paste, but you get cell format as well

.

**Version 1**

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MergeRows1() 'Fast - Array + Dictionary
    Dim ws As Worksheet, arr As Variant, r As Long, c As Long, d As Object
    Dim tc As Long, mc As Long, resultArr As Variant, rVals As Variant

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    arr = ws.UsedRange.Offset(1).Resize(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1)
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr)            'rows (start under headers)
        For c = 2 To UBound(arr, 2)     'cols (first col = ids)
            If Len(arr(r, 1)) = 0 Or Len(arr(r, c)) = 0 Then Exit For
            If d.Exists(arr(r, 1)) Then
                d(arr(r, 1)) = d(arr(r, 1)) & "||" & arr(r, c)
                mc = UBound(Split(d(arr(r, 1)), "||"))
                If mc > tc Then tc = mc
            Else
                d(arr(r, 1)) = "||" & arr(r, c)
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    tc = tc + 1:    ReDim resultArr(1 To d.Count, 1 To tc)
    For r = 1 To d.Count
        resultArr(r, 1) = d.Keys()(r - 1)
        rVals = Split(d.Items()(r - 1), "||")
        For c = 1 To UBound(rVals)
            resultArr(r, c + 1) = rVals(c)
        Next c
    Next r
    ws.UsedRange.Offset(1).Resize(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1).Clear
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(d.Count + 1, tc)) = resultArr
End Sub
```

---

.

**Version 2**

---

```
Public Sub MergeRows2() 'Slow - Copy / Paste (with cell formatting)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, maxC As Long, r As Long, tc As Range, tLC As Long, nLC As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    maxC = ws.Columns.Count

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For r = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'rows (start under headers)
        Set tc = ws.Cells(r, "A")
        If Len(tc.Offset(1)) = 0 Then Exit For
        While tc.Value2 = tc.Offset(1).Value2
            tLC = ws.Cells(r, maxC).End(xlToLeft).Column
            nLC = ws.Cells(r + 1, maxC).End(xlToLeft).Column
            ws.Range(tc.Offset(1, 1), tc.Offset(1, nLC - 1)).Copy tc.Offset(, tLC)
            ws.Rows(r + 1).Delete
            tLC = tLC + nLC - 1
        Wend
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

.

Test Data

[image: TestData]

Result

[image: Result]

Comment: @phantom234234: any feedback?